# How to highlight searched string only instead of complete row or cell in Angular 4 Material table?

Tags: angular, search, angular-material

Am using Angular material table to display data and using filter function search data. Now i want to highlight searched string only instead of complete row or cell in Angular 4 Material table.

Comment: I'm also interested on this ... I've tried with HTML tags as <b> or <em> but the text is displayed without interpreting them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to highlight the matching results by using HTML tags as `<b>result</b>` (or even `<span class="highlight">result</span>` for a more customized style). In order to see HTML content inside cells you must use the `[innerHTML]=cellText` property binding instead of interpolation `{{cellText}}`.

An example would be the following:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let document" [innerHTML]="document.description"></mat-cell>
```

Where `document.description` already contains the HTML tags for highlighting.

See https://alligator.io/angular/innerhtml-binding-angular/ for more info